# Undefined imports when using webpack to bundle a library

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-modules

A while back I wrote a Web-gl based network vis library for a project. I wanted to bundle it up and release it primarily to use it in other projects.

I got most of the parts of the software to work but for some reason cant get imports and thigns to run properly. For example Ive combined everything in a final file which reads something like

```
// this is where I bundle everything up and export it
const PGL = {
  Graph,
  Geometry,
  GraphMethods,
  SampleData,
  Constructors,
  Drawing,
  Utilities,
  threeDWrapper,
  GraphDrawer,
  logStatus
};

export {PGL as pgl};
```

and then this index file is then bundled using webpack.

When I try to import the bundled file elsewhere though the imports fail and says

```
import not found : pgl
```

The import code reads something like :

```
import {pgl} from "../build/pgl.js";
```

The github for the project is here : https://github.com/range-et/PGL
Any help is appreciated